# Translate data in MySQL database into another with slightly different structure?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, migration

I did some research on this and couldn't find many introductory resources for a beginner so I'm looking for a basic understanding here of how the process works. The problem I'm trying to solve is as such: I want to move data from an old database to a new one with a slightly different structure, possibly mutating the data a little bit in the process. Without going into the nitty gritty detail.. what are the general steps involved in doing this?

From what I gathered I would either be...

- writing a ton of SQL queries manually (eesh)
- using some complex tool that may be overkill for what I'm doing

There is a lot of data in the database so writing `INSERT` queries from a SQL dump seems like a nightmare. What I was looking for is some way to write a simple program that inserts logic like `for each row in the table "posts", take the value of the "body" attribute and put it in the "post-body attribute of the new database` or something like that. I'm also looking for functionality like `append a 0 to the data in the "user id" column then insert it in the new database` (just an example, the point is to mutate the data slightly).

In my head I can easily construct the logic of how the migration would go very easily (definitely not rocket science here).. but I'm not sure how to make this happen on a computer to iterate over the ridiculous amount of data without doing it manually. What is the general process for doing this, and what tools might a beginner want to use? Is this even a good idea for someone who has never done it before?

**Edit:** by request, here is an example of a mutation I'd like to perform:

Old database: table "posts" with an attribute `post_body` that is a `varchar 255`. 
New database: table "posts" with an attribute `body"` that is a `text` datatype.

Want to take `post-body` from the old one and put it in `body` in the new one. Realize they are different datatypes but they are both technically strings and should be fine to convert, right? Etc. a bunch of manipulations like this.

Comment: this type of thing should be doable, but could you give some before and after examples? In general, you can either (a) create the new table's structure as step 1, then populate it from the old one as step 2 with [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) or (b) create an populate the table in a single step with [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html).

Comment: Sure, I'll update the main post with some examples. I'm mostly just wondering the general workflow of what I'll have to do i.e. am I going to be writing manual SQL statements etc.

Comment: Updated with a sample operation.

Comment: Also worth noting, the new table already exists and has valid data in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the most time-consuming step of a database conversion is understanding both the old and the new structure, and establishing the correspondance of fields in each structure.

Compared to that, the time it takes to write the corresponding SQL query is ridiculously short.

> for each row in the table "posts", take the value of the "body" attribute and put it in the "post-body attribute of the new database

```
INSERT INTO newdb.postattribute (id, attribute, value)
SELECT postid, 'post-body', body FROM olddb.post;
```

In fact, the tool that allows such data manipulation is... SQL! Really, this is already a very high-level language.

Comment: I guess I'll be SQL then. Thanks for the example, I think I can modify that template to get the rest of the data where I need it.